Doctors retaining images of ID cards?
There's another question about whether you can be compelled to show identification to a medical provider.
But it's not just showing your drivers license or state identification card—nowadays they insist you have to hand it over so that they can scan it (and, presumably, retain the images).  One lab I've used made hardcopies of my drivers license in plain view of me.

Can I show the card so somebody can visually check that it's me but prohibit them from making a copy?

If I prohibit them from making a copy, can they deny me non-emergency care?  Or will they treat me but leave me to file the insurance claim myself?

If I have a PPO, would it still be covered as in-network if I have to file the claim?


[California, United States]
I don't understand why providers (especially the smaller private practices) want to take on the additional liability of storing even more identifying data alongside their patients' sensitive medical information.

The staff at one provider's office, after I told them I did not want them to scan my drivers license, surreptitiously photographed me standing at the reception desk and attached it to my records.  I discovered this several visits later when the doctor turned her screen toward me to show me some test results.  There, in a window  above the lab report, was the picture next to all of my identifying information.  On the way out, I spotted a PC camera taped down to counter near the reception desk with a long USB extension cable leading back toward the receptionist's computer.  I'm no longer a patient there.

I don't see much additional liability in a provider collecting a lower class of sensitive information (personally identifiable information), and storing it alongside a higher class of sensitive information (protected health information). PHI is a subset of PII with greater restrictions - if they're already handling your sensitive medical data, they should be able to handle your less sensitive personal data.

Somebody with your medical records and your primary ID can do more damage than somebody with just your medical data.  Especially since a smaller provider generally doesn't have all your medical information to lose, but the ID is pretty universal.

I always assumed scanning ID cards and/or asking for SSN was to make it easier to track you down if you didn't pay your bills. I've had practices want my minor children's SSNs. I've always refused and they've never required them.

Most insurance companies used SSNs as patient identifiers.
Doctors would routinely ask for SSNs because that was the ID number they'd need to bill your insurance. Some states, notably California, passed laws prohibiting use of SSNs as identifiers for health insurance, but those laws weren't airtight. Companies issued cards with unique identifiers but many still use SSNs as identifiers in their databases (leading to disasters like the Anthem breach). Doctors continue to request SSNs out of habit and continuing use of old forms. I've never had a problem withholding my SSN.

@NuclearHoagie:  PHI is more sensitive, but it is not necessarily more restricted.  PHI is covered by federal HIPAA regulations, which have supremacy over state laws that, in some cases, would apply more stringent restrictions than HIPAA does.  For example, in California, you can compel a business to correct or delete errors in your PII, but not in your PHI.  You can ask your doctor to correct mistakes they entered into your medical records, and if you are persistent, they might.  (BTW, your medical record is likely overflowing with errors.)

@AdrianMcCarthy While all of that is true, I can't think of an instance where it would be acceptable to disclose PHI but not PII. If you trust your doctor's office has procedures to appropriately handle your PHI, they should be able to handle your PII as well. There are of course malicious actors and mistakes, but the marginal liability of collecting a small amount of PII when you're already collecting a large amount of PHI seems rather tiny.

@AdrianMcCarthy While I expect my insurance company has my SSN on file (they need it for the ACA tax form), I don't think it's ever been used as my customer ID. The ID on my insurance card has always been a totally different number.

@Barmar: My last employer self-insured their employee healthcare plans and outsource administration of them to Anthem. I joined before ACA. Anthem had a data breach, compromising our SSNs. I complained to our benefits managers that they never should have given our SSNs to Anthem given the California law prohibits use of SSNs as patient IDs. They explained that the California law only applies to the ID cards and that Anthem (and other insurers) still required SSNs as patient identifiers. The ACA reporting burden is on the insurer (my employer), so ACA didn't require them to give SSNs to Anthem.

@AdrianMcCarthy Since the company was presumably outsourcing the reporting function along with all other management of the healthcare plan, that seems to necessitate providing them with the necessary data. When a company self-insures, it just means that they're paying for it, not running an insurance company. (Although there have been companies that did everything, and eventually turned that division into a public business.)

While patients can be compelled to show identification to retrieve treatment, no federal or state law requires providers to retain copies of the identification cards.  Retaining copies increases legal risk for the provider, especially in some states that have more stringent reporting requirements for data breaches.  Thus some legal advisors recommend healthcare providers not capture or retain images of ID cards.
Some ID cards have bar codes that contain information beyond the human-readable information provided on the card.  What information those codes contain is not disclosed by the state authorities.  A medical provider who retains a scan of an ID card thus becomes responsible for maintaining control and security for information whose sensitivity is unknown.
If a medical practice nevertheless makes it a policy to scan and retain images of ID cards despite these risks to themselves and their patients, a patient who refuses to allow their ID card to be captured can be denied non-emergency treatment.


One lab I've used made hardcopies of my drivers license in plain view
of me. . . .
I don't understand why providers (especially the smaller private
practices) want to take on the additional liability of storing even
more identifying data alongside their patients' sensitive medical
information.

Labs are often required to document that the person who body or whose salvia, pee, stool, etc. that they did work on is the same as the person it is claimed to be from. Often lab reports are relied upon by insurance companies, law enforcement, probation or parole officers, courts in lawsuits, etc. Also, if you have a common name, there is a risk of data entry error leading to an assignment of the results to the wrong person. The same concerns could also apply to a doctor's physical examination of a patient.
A simple intentional misrepresentation in the description of the patient who is the subject of the lab tests is also a serious concern (usually this is done to fake a clean controlled substances check, to fake a doping test in elite sports, or to provide health care to someone who lacks health care with or without the consent of the insured).
If they have a copy of the ID in the file, they can prove who was tested. Also, given that they have to keep the medical file secure in any case, having one more item of data in a file that already contained personal identifying data about the person sampled, is not a meaningful exposure to additional liability. In contrast, not being able to prove definitively who was the source of the sample could be a source of serious liability.
Indeed, even if there is a misrepresentation and a fake ID is used, that may be possible to determine that there was fraud from a copy of the fake ID in a way that it wouldn't have been possible if the patient's name were simply entered into the system.
While there could be isolated circumstances where accuracy confirmation of the patient's identity wasn't a concern, it almost never does harm to include it in the file. So, it makes sense from a firm level policy perspective to require this in every case, except a medical emergency where the identity of the patient may not even be known.
A patient's concern about a medical provider who already has personal identifying information and medical information having their driver's license or state ID as well is patently unreasonable.

If I prohibit them from making a copy, can they deny me non-emergency
care?

Yes. They can deny care in a non-emergency setting for almost any reason (except, of course, race, national origin, and the other "usual suspects" and a few additional reasons specific to health care such as the fact that they have a Medicaid provider if they accept some Medicaid patients).

Or will they treat me but leave me to file the insurance claim myself?
If I have a PPO, would it still be covered as in-network if I have to
file the claim?

It is quite likely that the insurance company requires a copy of the patient's ID in non-emergency settings to prevent use of a health insurance policy by someone who isn't authorized to do so, and to make it easier to audit fraud cases when they occur.
Anecdotally, when I was in my late teens and early twenties, at a time when the percentage of people in that age group who were uninsured was much higher, this form of insurance fraud was quite common.
For example, a young woman with an uninsured friend with a suspected urinary tract infection or STD, might allow the uninsured friend to use her health insurance card to get that suspected condition tested with an out of pocket cost far less than what a cash paying patient would pay.

"[P]atently unreasonable" seems a bit harsh.  There are many  contexts where ID is checked but not retained by organizations that already have lots of PII.  When an employer checks a new employee's documents to ensure they have a right to work in the U.S., somebody from the company certifies they checked the documents, they don't make and retain copies.  Likewise when obtaining a "REALID" card or having a document notarized.  Medical data breaches are common.  Two members of my family have had providers report theft of all of their patients' electronic records.

@AdrianMcCarthy But, almost all of the substantive information from an ID is present in the medical records anyway and has to be (e.g. name, date of birth, sex, height, weight). But the necessity for this is pretty clear. The copy of an ID is an authentication tool, it doesn't materially change what can be discovered from a data breach.

We don't know that. Decades ago, California added a third track to the magnetic stripe on driver's licenses, that was recorded at a higher data density that the first two. It is known that the lower density tracks simply record the info from the front of the license, but California resisted disclosing what was on the third. Now licenses have multiple optical codes. One is the info from the front of the license, but states refuse to disclose what's encoded in the other(s) (security through obscurity).

The Driver Privacy Protection Act allows businesses to scan licenses to verify the data in the barcode matches the printed data, but in most cases, they are not allowed redisclose the data (some have suggested that this means they cannot even retain it) except in specific enumerated circumstances. A medical provider who send an image including the secret optical code(s) to an insurance company doesn't know what data they are transmitting, but it's attached to PII, and the recipient may know how to read it.

@AdrianMcCarthy The statute covers disclosures by the state itself and has lots of exceptions, most notably, that you can subpoena the information for use in almost any kind of litigation.

@ohwileke:  The last is not exclusively about what the states can do--see the redisclosure section.  "'It is not illegal for businesses to scan your license in order to verify your age or check for fraud, but they are not supposed to collect and market this data,' Levin said."  None of the exceptions are relevant to a doctor's office retaining an image of an ID and transmitting it (e.g., to an insurance company).
